# It does not give me error in code, MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql

This is the error:

> run:
>   Mon Mar 25 05:22:00 SGT 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
>   Mar 25, 2019 5:22:15 AM mypackage.profile jButton6ActionPerformed
>   SEVERE: null
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42PreparedStatement@41399cae: SELECT * FROM persons WHERE id ' at line 1**
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

And then this is the code:

```
private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    String id = txtid.getText();
    if (id.isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ID field is empty");
        return;
    }
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE id = "+ Integer.parseInt(id) + ";";
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Is this right?\n" + sql);
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = ps.executeQuery(String.valueOf(ps));
        if(rs.next()){
        txtln.setText(rs.getString("lastName"));
        txtfn.setText(rs.getString("firstName"));
        txtadrs.setText(rs.getString("address"));
        txtcity.setText(rs.getString("city"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(profile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}                                        

private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    dispose();
    new menu().setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `rs = ps.executeQuery(String.valueOf(ps));` is incorrect in the context of [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). Since you already supplied SQL when creating `ps` you want to do `rs = ps.executeQuery();`.

There are few big problems with your code:

1. Never run JDBC from Swing EDT because you will block the Swing UI refresh events and your application will freeze. You must schedule long running task like SQL queries in a background tasks, see [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) docs.
2. Never use `String` concatenation to build SQL. In your example there is no  problem yet but if `id` would be `String` instead of `int` you would have a [SQL Injection vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Since you already created `PreparedStatement` use:

   ```
   ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE id = ?");
   ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(id));
   ```
3. Close `PreparedStatement` after it was processed if you don't plan to reuse it, use [`try-with-resources` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).
4. MySQL doesn't require a trailing `;` at the end of the statement. This is needed only if you enabled multi-statement execution.

Comment: actually some drivers do not allow `;` at the end of statements (I believe oracle 9 is one)

Comment: Thanks you so much! Putting the value of sql in rs = ps.executeQuery(String.valueOf(ps)); solved the problem! :)

Comment: @locrasm999 That's the wrong solution. You're forcing the SQL to be parsed twice. Use the solution in this answer.